Solving $\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ through substitution.
I'm trying to solve the double integral
$$\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
by substitution, i.e. $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$.
The intrgral then becomes $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{\cos{\theta}}}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$. I'm not sure about the upper limit in $r$ though: $\dfrac{a}{\cos{\theta}}$; is it correct? And if so, I can't seem to solve the integral.. Does it even exist?
Thank you for any advice!

Did you notice that $\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is undefined when $x=y=0$? Besides, did you notice that $\frac a{\cos\theta}$ is undefined when $\theta=\frac\pi2$ and also when $\theta=\frac{3\pi}2$?

Note that, per symemtry
$$
\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{d}x{d}y=4 \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{d}x{d}y\\
=8 \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{\cos{\theta}}}{d}r{d}\theta= 8 \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac a{\cos \theta}d\theta=16a\tanh^{-1}(\tan\frac\pi8)
$$

Alternatively, without converting to polar coordinates:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-a}^a \int_{-a}^a \frac{dy\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
&= 8a \int_0^1 \int_0^u \frac{dv\,du}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} & (x,y)=(au,av);\text{ symmetry} \\
&= 8a \int_0^1 \frac{dw}{\sqrt{1+w^2}} \cdot \int_0^1 du & w=uv \\
&= \boxed{8a \operatorname{arsinh}1}
\end{align*}$$
